# How to download excel (.xls) file from API in postman for suite run?

Tags: postman-collection-runner

For Single request,I can able to download the response output in excel format by chose an option 'Send and Download'. Can anyone help me to download the same using collection runner in postman.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available in Postman Collection Runner yet! However, there is a workaround if you would like to do it in **Newman**.

As Newman is built on Node.js, you can extend it in a Node.js code as you can see in the below example.

https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/413#issuecomment-316116450

Running the script above essentially does the same thing as `newman run ...` and also saves the responses to files